# How do I use my ip address to connect to my iis 7 server?

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net-mvc

I have windows 7 and I want to host a site for testing purposes. Now I want to set it up so I can type in my ip address in and it will load up my site. This way I can go to any computer type in my ip and it will load it up.

Now I been able to set up IIS 7 so that it loads the default page when I type in localhost. I also got it to load up my webpage when I type in localhost/MySite but I can't get it to do MyIp/Mysite

It won't load up. I am not sure what I need to do to get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't done so, you must enable port forwarding in your router so that it may send those requests to the server running on the specified port.

Comment: I believe iis is using port 80. So do I need to set it up for port 80?

Comment: I also tried this just down. I went to my router and put 4118 as my port. Then I went to my iis and did binding and put this "http" and port = "4118" and left the rest blank. I then tried to go http://MyIPAddress:4118/Test but I just get "problem loading Page" error

Comment: You also need to make sure that you have a static IP (wan) at your router or a good way to figure out what your IP is when it changes.  Yes, by default IIS7 binds to port 80

Comment: I got it working thanks. Seems that windows firewall was blocking my port and did not tell me. I don't know why it did not work on port 80. Maybe it is being blocked too but windows firewall is a bit to crazy looking now and I don't know how to easily find if it is blocked or not.